# Does Azure's Durable Functions support a Service Bus Queue Trigger in Javascript

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am attempting to follow the tutorial from Microsoft of creating a Durable Function in the Azure Portal.  In following the Tutorial I am seeing that the Portal only has templates based off a HTTP Trigger.  I was wondering if Durable Functions for Javascript can support Service Bus Queue Triggers?

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-create-portal#create-an-orchestrator-function

Answer (score 0):

After playing with the function.json and **luckily** finding the following blog post, I did get an Azure Durable Function written in Javascript to be kicked off via the arrival of a message on a Service Bus Queue.

Blog Post: https://simonagren.github.io/intro-durable/